# Recursive AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Currently I am working on a project using AngularJS and I need to create a directive which is able to display (and alter) a "recursive structure" - something similar to a family. 
The structure defined in the controller looks like this:

```
$scope.members = [
            { firstName: 'Andrei', lastName: 'Croitoriu', age: 32 },
            { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25, members: [
                {
                  firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', age: 24
                }
              ]}
           ];
```

I've managed to implement the directive which display the structure, but now I am struggling to implement a "Add Member" feature. Basically for each member I want to have a button next to it and be able to add a new member to the node. I would like to have a single method defined in the controller - all my attempts so far failed so in the plnkr code attached I've removed all attempts (left just a simple addMember method which just adds a new member to the top level collection.

Can anybody suggest any idea on how to pass the addMember method to the directives and implement the behavior I expect?

My code can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/hRzQiW?p=info

Thank you in advance!

Andrei

Comment: you want to add a member to the member's family members?

Comment: yes, I want when I click on add member button for a member to add a new member to it's members property. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: ok my answer is wrong then. i deleted the plunker link, but basic idea is add the `addMember` function in isolated scope

Comment: i have updated my answer with plunker link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fast tuning is to put `addMember` in `familyMember` directive, as the directive scope is isolated, the function under controller's scope is not accessible.

see the plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/h6vZu7?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @elaijuh! Seems to do the job for what I need!